# Outer vs. Super class

Tags: java, inheritance, inner-classes

Does super has higher priority than outer class?

Consider we have three classes:

1. ClassA
2. ClassB
3. Anonymous class in ClassB that extends ClassA

ClassA.java:

```
public class ClassA {
    protected String var = "A Var";

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("A foo()");
    }
}
```

ClassB.java:

```
public class ClassB {
    private String var = "B Var";

    public void test() {

        new ClassA() {
            public void test() {
                foo();
                System.out.println(var);
            }
        }.test();
    }

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("B foo()");
    }
}
```

When I call `new ClassB().test()`, I get the following output (which is pretty much expected):

```
A foo()
A Var
```

Question: Is it defined somewhere that inner class takes (methods and members) first from the super class and then from the outer class or is it <strike>JVM</strike> compiler implementation dependent? I have looked over the JLS(§15.12.3) but couldn't find any reference for that, maybe it is pointed out there but I misunderstood some of the terms?

Comment: I tried to follow the logic in the JLS but didn't have my coffee yet ;-) From experience I'd say: I'm **pretty** sure that this is well-specified and **not** implementation-dependent. And *if* it were implementation-dependent, then it would depend on the compiler and not on the JVM, as that decision is done at compile-time.

Comment: @Joachim - I wrote JVM by mistake, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [6.3.1 Shadowing Declarations](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.3.1):

> A declaration *d* of a method named *n* **shadows the declarations of any other methods named *n* that are in an enclosing scope** at the point where *d* occurs throughout the scope of *d*.

Which *may* be interpreted as "the declaration of `foo` (inherited from `ClassA`) shadows the declaration of any other methods named `foo` that are in an enclosing scope (`ClassB`) at the point where `foo` occurs, throughout the scope of `foo`."

Also relevant - section [15.12.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.1):

> **15.12.1 Compile-Time Step 1: Determine Class or Interface to Search**
>
> The first step in processing a method invocation at compile time is to figure out the name of the method to be invoked and which class or interface to check for definitions of methods of that name. There are several cases to consider, depending on the form that precedes the left parenthesis, as follows:
>
> - If the form is *MethodName*, then there are three subcases:
>
>   - **If it is a simple name, that is, just an Identifier**, then the name of the method is the Identifier. If the Identifier appears within the scope (§6.3) of a visible method declaration with that name, then there must be an enclosing type declaration of which that method is a member. Let T be the innermost such type declaration. **The class or interface to search is T**.
>   - If it is a qualified name of the form TypeName.Identifier, then [...]
>   - In all other cases, the qualified name has the form FieldName.Identifier; then [...]

Comment: @aioobe - Thanks, but it is still not clear to me, because ClassB methods and members are in the scope of the anonymous class. I might be missing that, but I still see no priority for the super class (ClassA in my example) in what you posted.

Comment: Hmm.. true. I'll see if I can find something more specific.

Comment: @aioobe - thanks again, I hope you don't think I'm sending you to to the work for me, I just looked it over and over again and couldn't figure it out...

Comment: Oh no. I enjoy browsing the JLS.. I learn something new every time :-)

Comment: Also §6.5.6 Meaning of Expression Names (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#129350)

Comment: @aioobe - "6.3.1 Shadowing Declarations" - this is not just also relevant, but explains what I missed. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah. Your first comment sort of explains why the first quote is actually less relevant than the second. Feel free to rewrite the answer as you see fit. (Otherwise I'll just leave it as it stands now.)

Comment: Thanks. That's better :-) Great question by the way. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are always going to get `"A var"`.

This is because your `test()` method implementation is being defined on an anonymous subclass of `A`. I don't think you can access the `B.var` instance variable within your `test()` method unless you explicitly refer to the outer class using `ClassB.this.var`.

Comment: @The Captain - if I remove `var` from ClassA, I do get the var from ClassB. I am trying to understand and get confirmation about what should happen in case I don't remove it.

Comment: sure... I think this is because `ClassA`.`var` is shadowing `ClassB`.`var` in your example. So while both definitions exist, referencing `var` from `A.test()` will always get the `ClassA` version.