# Output of Java program

Tags: java, oop

I am a Java beginner.
Can anyone explain why is it printing output 2?

```
interface Foo {
    int bar();
}

public class Beta {
    class A implements Foo {
        public int bar() {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    public int fubar(final Foo foo) {
        return foo.bar();
    }

    public void testFoo()// 2
    {
        class A implements Foo {
            public int bar() {
                return 2;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(fubar(new A()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Beta().testFoo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

That is because you redefined `Class A` here:

```
    class A implements Foo {
        public int bar() {
            return 2;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(fubar(new A()));
```

So when you do `return foo.bar();` you return `2`

Comment: I think the confusion may be caused because the call to "new A()" is happening within the context of the testFoo() method, not fubar().

Comment: +1 for speedy correct response. But @Neal, I like to avoid the term 'redefine' because in some other languages, you can actually redefine the method itself. I like the term 'hide'. Thoughts?

Comment: @Dilum, yes, but how do you put `hide` in this context?

Comment: I guess something along the lines of 'within Beta.testFoo(), the inner class Beta.A is hidden by the method-scoped inner class A, because the name is re-used.'

Answer (score 3):

Because the innermost definition of A is in the `testFoo()` method, and its method `bar()` return 2.

You may also find the [answer to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867287/outer-vs-super-class/5867408#5867408) from today interesting.

Answer (score 0):

When you say, `System.out.println(fubar(new A()));`

the class A created is the one defined inside testFoo().

Answer (score 0):

There are many places in java where you can hide a broader name with a more local name. This is true of parameters vs member variables, class names etc. In your case, you are hiding Beta.A with the A you defined in the method.